# Check if running phonegap or apk

Tags: phonegap

I have a code that will not run if the app is running via Phonegap (it will completly stop the script), will only run as an apk (needs to be built). How can I create an if that will check if its in phonegap or a standalone apk?

Answer (score 0):

I test my apps using IIS (localhost). I use to check if the url contained "localhost", later found out about checking window.cordova to determine if the app is running as Cordova App.

**Example:**

```
function isRunningLocalhost() {

    if (window.cordova) {
        console.log('runningLocalhost() - False In Cordova');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        console.log('runningLocalhost() - True Running Localhost');
       return true;
   }
}

if (isRunningLocalhost() === true) 
{     
  //Not running as an APK
}
```

Comment: Mm, thats usefull in a way, half the times I test in localhost. But if I test with phonegap how can I check if its being emulated with phonegap or built in apk?

Comment: window.cordova will only return True if the app is running on a device from an APK / IPA. Otherwise it will return False. I use window.cordova === false to bypass or mock plugin logic when running on localhost, otherwise the actual plugn runs (camera, what ever) vs. my mock code.